# Handle null values in spring expression language

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have the following code using spring expression language:

```
StandardEvaluationContext stdContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
stdContext.setVariable("emp", filterInputData); 
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();     
parser.parseExpression("#emp.?[name.toLowerCase().contains('Hari')]").getValue(stdContext);
```

where *emp* is the name of the bean. Here the name can be null and when calling `name.toLowerCase()` I am getting a nullpointer exception. How to handle the null values in this scenario? I need to call `toLowercase()` for only non-null values.

Comment: `toLowerCase().contains('Hari')` is always `false`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
"#emp.name != null ? #emp.name.toLowerCase().contains('hari') : null"
```

or

```
"#emp.name != null ? #emp.name.toLowerCase().contains('hari') : false"
```

depending on what you want back when the name is missing.

Actually, this short form works too...

```
"#emp.name != null ? toLowerCase().contains('hari') : null"
```

BTW, in your original question...

```
name.toLowerCase().contains('Hari')
```

will never return true (H is upper case).

Or, Elvis is your friend...

```
Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#emp.name?:'no name found'");
value = expression.getValue(context, String.class).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your answer. In My case, The employee is a collection of object. So I need to get the name from the collection . I tried with "#emp.?[name != null ? toLowerCase().contains('hari') : null]" , but it is not working and I am getting an message saying that the toLowercase method does not exist in EmployeeDto, Could you please help me to fix this issue. Many thanks

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to use collection selection. If your collection is a map, this works fine... "#emp['name'] != null ? #emp['name'].toLowerCase().contains('hari') : false"

Comment: It worked, Many thanks for your support and helping me to find a solution

Comment: It feels like `name?.toLowerCase()` should also help

Answer (score -1):

Can you Autowire this bean to your class?

Something like:

```
public class YourClass{ 
    @Autowire
    private Employee emp

    public boolean func(){
        if (emp.getName() != null){
            return emp.getName().toLowerCase().contains('Hari');
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```